# Can I completely disable ASP.NET in IIS, together with all side effects?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, iis-7.5

I'm using IIS 7.5 on Server 2008 R2 to run non-ASP sites, and they don't use .NET either.

Can ASP.NET be completely disabled/uninstalled, so that no ASP.NET security updates are required, and to fix minor annoyances like the appearance of `aspnet_client` directories etc?

Answer (score 1):

I think the asp.net features are installed with IIS.  Have you tried disabling the mappings? You could probably also filter out aspx extensions.

Comment: I have added a `<clear/>` to the handlers section of each site, but it left me wondering what other configuration elements IIS can change like this, or whether I can just disable ASP.NET to save the trouble.

Comment: @romkyns For the server, go to "Request Filtering" click Deny File Extension and add aspx, cs, vb, asax, etc.  It'll effectively disable asp.net.  You can't remove asp.net without removing iis.

Comment: If you want to host websites without having .net at all, I'd suggest looking at Apache, Apache Tomcat, zope,  bottle.py, node.js or any number of other non .net free webservers